# Powerbi to return a 'NA' using the IF that is used in a std table

Tags: if-statement, powerbi

I have a code in a powerbi table that displays all. It basically counts how long a particular task is performed for mgt. It was done by someone else. I am trying to find out how to get the rows to display a 'No Data' or 'NA' if there is no data. I tried several approaches but could not get it to work. Any suggestions? Linda from Wisconsin.

```
TimeTaken = 
//----CALCULATIONS
VAR DIFF = 'Opened'[Resolved] - 'Opened'[Opened]
VAR NumOfMinutes = DIFF * 24
    * 60
VAR DAYS =
    IF ( DIFF >= 1, INT ( DIFF ), BLANK () )
VAR HOURS =
    INT ( ( DIFF - DAYS ) * 24 )
VAR MINUTES = NumOfMinutes
    - ( DAYS * 24
    * 60 )
    - ( HOURS * 60 )

//---TEXTS
VAR DaysText =
    IF ( DAYS >= 1, FORMAT ( DAYS, "00" ) & "days" )
        //ELSE ("No Data")  >>>>> this not working.. I deleted some
VAR HoursText =
    FORMAT ( HOURS, "00" ) & "hrs"
VAR MinutesText =
    FORMAT ( MINUTES, "00" ) & "mins"

RETURN
    COMBINEVALUES ( " ", DaysText, HoursText, MinutesText )
```

Comment: Hi you can replace your last line with below code 
Return 
IF (
    ISBLANK ( DaysText ) && ISBLANK ( HoursText )
        && ISBLANK ( MinutesText ),
    "NA",
    COMBINEVALUES ( " ", DaysText, HoursText, MinutesText )
)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that now. I appreciate it much! Does it mean modify the COMBINEVALUES? Thx

Comment: No, combinevalue remain as it is, we are just putting condition for validation if all values are blank then return NA else return combinevalues

Comment: It seems the dates are not calculating correctly.. some days show like over 55-100+ days. I think the days calculations is somewhat messed up. hmmm

Comment: Oh, I thought calculation is right and issue is with return NA if data is blank. You can ask that question as well for correct calculation by providing some sample data with expected output. :)

Comment: Hmm let me check and send some data... give me a few mins.. network slow.... feels like Monday.. lol

Comment: Never mind. I think it is correct. Thanks a lot Sam Shri. Any good sites to learn DAX? I am kinda new in this.. problem is PowerBI has many peripheral knowledge requirements (sql, some code, dax and several others)

Comment: You can learn basic dax functions from this website https://www.tutorialspoint.com/power_bi/dax_basics_in_power_bi.htm and dax required practice which you can do by following exercise from this website https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/power-bi/exercises/

Comment: Just a quick question. I wonder if it is possible to format the days if >10 days to be in Red?

Comment: Sorry newbie question. where do I accept it as an answer?

Comment: Yes you can format the days with conditional formatting in power bi..its bit hard to explain a bit in comments but if you search you will get a good examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can try below code. Just replace your last two line with this code.

```
 RETURN 
IF (
        ISBLANK ( DaysText ) && ISBLANK ( HoursText )
            && ISBLANK ( MinutesText ),
        "NA",
        COMBINEVALUES ( " ", DaysText, HoursText, MinutesText )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks Sam! . If you can tell me say a Days value is more than 7 days make it Red I appreciate!.

Comment: You need value as Red in visual right? if yes then what type of visual it is?